# kaddish of a siyum on shabbos?

Tags: shabbat, sources-mekorot, kaddish, siyum

I heard once that the special kaddish recited after a siyum is replaced by a regular kaddish dirabbanan when the siyum takes place on Shabbos. 
Is this correct or perhaps just a minhag of some?
Is there a source for this in Halacha?

Comment: Some do this on any day without Tachanun, and some say the regular kaddish always.

Comment: I've made siyums on Shabbat and always said the siyum kaddish.

Comment: @AA source? Is there an actual halachic basis?

Comment: @Jew-Duh What do you mean actual halakhic basis? The whole thing is just a late minhag. The history is probably that in Ashkenaz Kaddish HaGadol was only said at a funeral, and then people started saying it at Siyumim on Yahrtzeits, then at all Siyumim. Alternatively, the Yeminites say it for every Kaddish Derabanan. But there's no reason a Siyum should be different halachically. (People probably feel special when they say a special kaddish which helps the practice stick. And/or being printed in the back popular editions of the Talmud)

Comment: I have been at siyyumim on Shabbat & the siyum kaddish was said.