# Is there a transliterated version of what you need to say at the end of the complete Mishna?

Tags: mishna, siyum, transliteration

My Hebrew is not very strong and I have to say everything at the end of Uktzin for a group of people that completed the entire Mishna in honour of a friend that passed away.  Does anyone have this transliterated?

Answer (score 4):

Here is the transliteration for the Hadran:

> Hadran alach hashishah sidrei mishnah vehadarach alan, datan alach hashishah sidrei mishnah vedatach alan. La nitnashei minach hashishah sidrei mishnah vela titnashei minan, la be'alma hadein vela be'alma de'atei.
>
> Yehi ratzon milefanecha eloheinu velohei avoteinu shetehe toratecha umanutenu ba'olam hazeh utehe imanu le'olam haba. Chanina bar papa, rami bar papa, nachman bar papa, acha'i bar papa, aba mari bar papa, rafram bar papa, rachish bar papa, surchav bar papa, ada bar papa, daru bar papa.
>
> Ha'arev na adonai eloheinu, et divrei toratecha befinu uvefifiyot amecha beit yisra'el. Venihyeh [kulanu,] anachnu vetze'etza'einu [vetze'etza'ei tze'etza'einu] vetze'etza'ei amecha beit yisra'el, kulanu yode'ei shemecha velomedei toratecha [lishmah]. Me'oyevai, techakmeni mitzvotecha, ki le'olam hi li. Yehi libi tamim bechukecha, lema'an lo evosh. Le'olam lo eshkach pikudecha, ki vam chiyitani. Baruch atah adonai, lamdeni chukecha. Amen amen amen, selah va'ed.
>
> Modim anachnu lefanecha adonai eloheinu velohei avoteinu shesamta chelkenu miyoshvei veit hamidrash, velo samta chelkenu miyoshvei keranot. She'anu mashkimim vehem mashkimim, anu mashkimim ledivrei torah, vehem mashkimim lidvarim betalim. Anu amelim vehem amelim, anu amelim umekablim sachar, vehem amelim ve'einam mekablim sachar. Anu ratzim vehem ratzim, anu ratzim lechayei ha'olam haba, vehem ratzim liv'er shachat, shene'emar: ve'atah elohim, toridem liv'er shachat, anshei damim umirmah lo yechetzu yemeihem, va'ani evtach bach.
>
> Yehi ratzon milefanecha adonai elohai, keshem she'azartani lesayeim hashishah sidrei mishnah ken te'azreni lehatchil mesechtot usefarim acherim ulesaimam, lilmod ulelamed, lishmor vela'asot ulekayem et kol divrei talmud toratecha be'ahavah. Uzechut kol hatana'im ve'amora'im utalmidei chachamim ya'amod li ulezar'i, shelo tamush hatorah mipi umipi zar'i vezera zar'i ad olam. Vatitkayem bi: Behithalechecha, tancheh otach, beshachbecha tishmor alecha, vahakitzota hi tesichecha. Ki vi yirbu yamecha, veyosifu lecha, shenot chayim. Orech yamim, biminah, bisemolah osher vechavod. Adonai oz le'amo yiten, adonai yevarech et amo vashalom.
>
> Yitgadal veyitkadash shemeh rabah. (Amen.) Be'alma di hu atid le'itchadata, ule'achaya'ah metayah, ule'asaka yat'hon lechayei alma, ulemivneh karta di yerushalem, uleshachlala heichaleh begavah, uleme'ekar palchana nuchra'ah min ar'ah, uleatava palchana di shemaya le'atreh, veyamlich kudsha berich hu bemalchuteh vikareh, [veyatzmach purkaneh vikarev meshicheh. (Amen.)] Bechayeichon uveyomeichon uvechayei dechol beit yisra'el, ba'agala uvizman kariv. Ve'imru: amen. (Amen. Yehe shemeh raba mevarach le'alam ule'almei almaya.) Yehe shemeh raba mevarach le'alam ule'almei almaya. Yitbarach veyishtabach veyitpa'ar veyitromam veyitnase veyithadar veyit'aleh veyit'halal shemeh dekudsha berich hu. (Berich hu.) Le'elah min kol (*Al Ha'Aseret Yemei Teshuvah:* Le'ala ule'elah mikol) birchatah veshirata tushbechata venechemata, da'amiran be'alma. Ve'imru: amen. (Amen.)
>
> Al yisra'el ve'al rabanan, ve'al talmideihon ve'al kol talmidei talmideihon, ve'al kol man de'askin be'oraita, di ve'atra hadein vedi vechol atar va'atar. Yehe lehon ulechon shelama raba, china vechisda verachamin, vechayin arichin, umezonei revichei, ufurkana min kodam avuhon di vishmaya [ve'ar'a]. Ve'imru: amen. (Amen.) Yehe shelama raba min shemaya vechayim [tovim] aleinu ve'al kol yisra'el. Ve'imru: amen. (Amen.) Oseh shalom bimromav, hu berachamav ya'aseh shalom aleinu, ve'al kol yisra'el. Ve'imru: amen. (Amen.)

The words in brackets reflect varying customs. The text is transliterated into the Modern Israeli Hebrew pronunciation, as it is most commonly used and somewhat "universal."

Comment: Wow thats alot of typing

Comment: @TrustMeI'mARabbi - Thank you. It took me one hour to type up.

Comment: @Michael - You're welcome! If you like an answer, consider marking it correct.

Comment: Not sure how to do that I am new here.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use a transliteration to say it in Hebrew, I would recommend just saying it in English instead.  You can find the English translation at the back of the Artscroll Mishna Uktzin, or (if you're willing to change "Tractate X" --> "the Six Orders of the Mishna" on the fly) any Artscroll Gemara that concludes a tractate.  I imagine Koren has it too, but I don't have that in front of me.

The one part that it might be worth saying in Aramaic is kaddish.  There are [multiple customs](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/84024/kaddish-of-a-siyum-on-shabbos#comment262141_84024), but the general practice I've seen is a modified version of kaddish derabbanan, where the beginning part is the same as the kaddish said at a cemetery, page 12 [here](http://www.chevrakadisha.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/prayer_book.pdf), up to "Y'hei sh'mei rabbah".  After that you can switch into kaddish derabbanan, side 1 [here](http://www.tefilacards.com/Sub%20Pages/Kadish%20Transliterated.htm), at the end of the first paragraph.

If that's too complicated, the other option is to just say the normal kaddish derabbanan.